# Does a warped engine block affect compression test?

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, compression, coolant

Check other questions, and did not see an answer.
Backstory: Driving around, discovered pin hole in radiator. Chose to drive home, since I was at my exit, and I lived right there. Blew head gasket. 
Fixes: Replaced radiator(Due to hole), Replaced water pump(found goo), and replaced head/gasket(It was cheaper).
I am doing a compression check, since coolant consumption problem seems to remain. Will I see any change in the results if my deck is warped? Or is the flat edge the only way to check a warped deck. Thanks for future answers.

Note to anyone else reading that might be wondering this: Engine has a block and a head, for the most part. The head seats on the head gasket, and the head gasket seats on the deck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a warped lower end can affect the compression test. A seriously warped head of block can lead to compression leakage through the small space between the head gasket and the head or block. But I don't think you have a bend block, I suspect you used your old head with a new head gasket? You need to have a specialized company 'flatten' the head. I don't know the correct English term but it's basically making the bottom of the head completely smooth and level again.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I meant I replaced both the head and head gasket (head/gasket), but I hope it's nothing major. I'm ok with redoing the install, but don't want to pay for a short block. I'll do the compression test, and hope it holds up.

Comment: Did you use an OEM headgasket, or something aftermarket?  Some of the inexpensive aftermarket ones don't necessarily work as well.  Even some of the high-end ones can be problematic as they may require special procedures to get them to seal.  If you went aftermarket, the solution might just be to get a fresh factory HG...

Comment: @ Brian I used factory HG, but aftermarket head and think they might just not match.

Answer (score 2):

You should have checked the flatness of the block deck with a feeler gauge and a straight edge before installing your new equipment. For instance one of my engines has a maximum value of .002" of "warp-age" when measured at any location on the surface of the block deck.  If out of spec, the block deck would need to be resurfaced, which when all is said and done, will raise compression by decreasing the cylinder volume but retaining the same bore and stroke.  Furthermore, if the block is made of cast iron and the head is aluminum there is a good chance that by torquing down the new aluminum head to a non-level cast iron block deck you have misshaped the head before ever turning the key.

Comment: I know. But this site requires reputation points, as you know, and choosing from available "0" answered questions left only a few questions I was ready to answer difinitivly to build those points.

Comment: Understood. Like I said, there is nothing wrong with your answering. Just didn't want you to be disappointed if you did not receive a response.